# Complete description of two electrons with spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We have two electrons described by the wave function $\phi(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,s_1,s_2;t)$ where $\left| \phi(t)\right\rangle$ is the state vector and $(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,s_1,s_2)$ is the index of each dimension in the vector. $\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2\in\mathbb{R}^3$. $s_1,s_2\in\{-{1\over2}\hbar,{1\over2}\hbar\}$ are the spins of each electron measured along some axis in space (but lets just say both are measured along the $z$ axis).

What are the first-quantization equation(s) that evolve the system? I am expecting the Schrodinger equation where the Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \hat{T} + \hat{V}_{Coulomb} + \hat{V}_{External}$, $\hat{V}_{Coulomb}$ is the classical (first quantization) Coulomb potential, and $\hat{V}_{External}$ is potential due to external forces. But I do not see how spin fits into this picture. How are spin and position states are affected when electrons interact via electromagnetism? I do not want to get into quantum field theory so I am hoping that a complete description of quantum particles in classical fields exists.

Please include the equations (probably Schrodinger) in your answer and define anything that I have have not already so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Spin is an ad hoc implementation in non-relativistic QM, so it's good to have a look at the relativistic Dirac equation, where the spin arises naturally - all the corrections concerning spin in the nonrelativistic case come from this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure

Comment: As you seem to already know; once you write down the Hamiltonian, the time evolution of the system is determined by Schrodinger's equation.  To write the Hamiltonian down precisely, you need to provide more context.  What interactions do you want to include?  What you've written down so far is sensible provided the only interaction between the electrons is Coulomb.  However, in the real world, there would also be a (negligible for all practical purposes) gravitational ineteraction between them for instance.  There is also spin-spin interaction etc. etc.

Comment: I am interested in the most generic two electron system so that I can understand the mathematical model of basic QM (non-relativistic and first quantization to start with). So free electrons. I left open the possibility of external interactions by including the external term that should be left as some unspecified function. It's not important and can be 0. I am only interested in interactions that have a significant impact on the evolution of the wave function. Gravity is negligible as you said and I believe the nuclear forces are too? Is the spin-spin interaction not mediated by the EM force?